# Setting a new default template for the creation of a page

Tags: themes, pages, page-template, theme-options

Right off the bat I would like to say that I am a WordPress noobie, so I'm really sorry if I infuriate you.

I've recently taken over the management of a clients website an have been sent a request to change the pre-selected "Default Layout" template to one we have created our self.

The client has recently hired new staff to create new page for them, and they keep forgetting to change the layout from Default to the custom template, I have been asked to make sure that our template is selected when the page loads so we can minimize mess-ups on their end.

I've spent about 3 hours looking for a solution, can any one suggest a way to do this or something similar?

Comment: Please view the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), it should be helpful. That and [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) you can achieve anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page template you are looking to overwrite is the `page.php` file. If you replace the code in that file with the code from your template (or delete it and rename your file to `page.php`), your problem should be taken care of.

Comment: This worked, cheers. I never considered just renaming the file, I tried to copy the contents and for whatever reason that didn't work